# SwiftUI apply view modifier to specific subviews in view hierarchy

Tags: ios, swiftui, hierarchy, subview, modifier

I'm curious on how does SwiftUI applies some of the available view modifiers like `keyboardShortcut`, which can be applied to any View but it will only work on the first Button child it finds down the view hierarchy:

> The target of a keyboard shortcut is resolved in a leading-to-trailing, depth-first traversal of one or more view hierarchies. [...] If multiple controls are associated with the same shortcut, the first one found is used.

Or same thing with `.navigationTitle`, which apparently you can place anywhere in the view hierarchy and it will be picked up by the next `NavigationView`, but how? I mean, **how can i do this in SwiftUI by myself?**

It would be awesome to just place some random view modifier which does this *magic* things to some items down the view hierarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those work using [`PreferenceKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/preferencekey/) you can define your own and then listen to changes on the `PreferenceKey` on the parent view while setting the value on some child view.

Some very basic example where you can set the title of `MyView` using a `PreferenceKey` somewhat similar how `navigationTitle` works

```swift
struct MyPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: String?

    static func reduce(value: inout String?, nextValue: () -> String?) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}

extension View {
    func myTitle(_ value: String) -> some View {
        preference(key: MyPreferenceKey.self, value: value)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MyView {
            VStack {
                Text("Test")
                    .myTitle("My Title Value")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MyView<Content>: View where Content: View {
    @State private var myTitle: String?
    @ViewBuilder var content: () -> Content
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            if let myTitle = myTitle {
                Text(myTitle)
                    .font(.callout)
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
            }
            
            content()
        }
        .onPreferenceChange(MyPreferenceKey.self) {
            myTitle = $0
        }
    }
}
```